# Cannot use my drupal installation after enabling new custom theme

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrapping

I keep geting this error message on every page request:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 167772160 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\mydrupal2\includes\theme.inc on line 98
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0100  142240  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0220  449448  drupal_bootstrap( ) ..\index.php:20
3   0.2050  3025040 _drupal_bootstrap_full( )   ..\bootstrap.inc:2259
4   0.6290  15508712    drupal_theme_initialize( )  ..\common.inc:5144
```

Increasing memory allowance has not had any effects. I try using drush to disable the offending theme or go back to the last working one, it's the same error message. I can't even use drush for anything else. It reports the same error message. I tried the SQL method on this [drupal.org page](https://www.drupal.org/node/200774). Same result.

Comment: Roll back your site from backup, using the backup you created just before you enabled the custom theme.

Comment: In your message the memory limit is about 160Mb, this is usally too low, have tried incrementing to 512Mb or 1024Mb just to test? If you have disabled the theme using the SQL method linked then your error is not comming form the theme, did you enable any other module before?

Comment: I think the problem is now from the drupal itself and not the theme. I suggest you clear the cache and restart the server and see if that would help.

Comment: @FreeRadical I don't have a backup

Comment: @AhmedJabar I can't do anything on drupal, even with drush. It's always this error message.

Comment: @tunic Every increase in memory has no effect. It's still the same error message, even after I set max-memory to 1G

Comment: Are you restarting the server after changing the php settings? Drush uses another php.ini file which is under `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. You should also update that file to allow drush more memory.

Comment: Well I see that you are using wamp. I don't know where wamp puts the php.ini files but look for `cli`.

Comment: If you are comfortable that the theme is no longer active, you can try clearing the cache manually, using phpMyAdmin, by emptying (not deleting) all tables that start with cache_  . If you are uncertain if the theme is still active, try going directly to an Admin page (if you have Seven set up as Admin theme) such as /admin/dashboard.  If you can get in, you may be able to clear the cache, or disable the theme for sure once you have access to the system

Answer (score 0):

theme.inc on line 98 is trying to collect theme's ancestors.

My bet is that your custom theme is wrong and it's telling Drupl that is a subtheme of itself, making Drupal the enter in an infinte loop that exhausts memory.

Double check your custom theme configuration or just move it away from Drupal directories so Drupal can't process it.

Comment: I have moved custom theme directory from drupal installation. Still no luck.

Comment: Same erorr in the same theme.inc?

Comment: yes. Same error message.

Comment: Then this is not the right answer. Sorry, I have no more ideas :(